Wine not properly uninstalled
So i installed wine a long time ago, However its pretty heavy so i decided to uninstall it.
However, There's still a wine folder in the x86 64 linux gnu Folder:
thearchcoder@thearchcoder-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF:/usr/lib$ ls | grep "^w"
w3m
waydroid
wine

How do i uninstall wine properly? Also, is it safe to remove this folder? Linux gnu seems important, So i am not sure if i should remove the wine folder.
I tried sudo apt remove wine, It still didin't remove it properly.

The "i tried sudo apt remove wine" was written because it kept saying "does not meet quality standards, tell us what u tried"

You have not said what is in the Wine folder so can not say if its important or not.

Where in your question did you say that? Please edit the question and add the additional info, not in comments.
